# Placeholders in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, placeholder

I'm trying to use a jQuery solution for placeholders in IE8 and IE9. I'm using conditional HTML tags to target the browsers, but the jQuery isn't working.

**Conditional HTML Tags**

```
<!--[if IE ]><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="no-js lt-ie10 ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

**jQuery Script**

```
if ($('html').is('.ie8, .ie9')) {
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Source: (http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html)